# How to use fufillment in Dialogflow with LINE integration

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es

My intent works fine in the Dialogflow chatbox and the initial welcome intent and the follow up intent are working however whenever I use a fulfilment and use conv.add or whatever it doesn't spit it out on the other end.

Again the logic works perfectly fine in DialogFlow and partially in LINE.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear but I think you use actions-on-google module for your chatbot. Since that module is created for Google Assistant you can not use it for other platforms. You can try dialogflow-fulfillment library for Line.